# Querying data from a sqlite database with sqlalchemy - need to include duplicates in result set

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

In my database, i have three tables:

```
class Element(Base):
 id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True);
 nodes = relationship('Node', secondary='element_node', 
 back_populates='elements',
                     order_by='ElementNode.node_position')
 .
 .   


class Node(Base):
 id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
 .
 .

class ElementNode(Base):
 node_id = 
 Column(Integer,ForeignKey('node.id_'),primary_key=True);
 element_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('element.id_'), 
 primary_key=True)

 node_position = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
 .
 .
```

The ElementNode table has some entries that look like this:

| node_id | element_id | node_position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 2 |
| 3 | 100 | 3 |
| 3 | 100 | 4 |
| 3 | 100 | 5 |

When i query this element object and use element.nodes, i only get node 1,2,3. But i need the duplicates as well when i call element.nodes, because they have a different node position .

I tried  adding a new relationship but i cant figure out the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to make ElementNode a full fledged class and not use secondary.  The pattern is called an association object: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object

```py
class Element(Base):
    elementNodes = relationship("ElementNode", back_populates="element")


class ElementNode(Base):
    element = relationship("Element", back_populates="elementNodes")
    node = relationship("Node", back_populates="elementNodes")

class Node(Base):
    elementNodes = relationship("ElementNode", back_populates="node")
```